# Exhausting enum in if-else statement in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

TypeScript (in strict mode) infers the return type of the following function as `1 | undefined`:

```
enum E {A, B};
const f = (x: E) => {
  if (x === E.A) {
    return 1;
  } else if (x === E.B) {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

How do I ensure the type would be inferred as a number (because the enum is exhausted)? Currently I add `... else { throw undefined; }`, but this means that if I forget to actually exhaust all options in the enum, TypeScript won't catch this. It works with the switch statement:

```
const g = (x: E) => {
  switch (x) {
    case E.A:
      return 1;
    case E.B:
      return 1;
  }
};
```

So it seems strange that it wouldn't work with if-else and I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: This seems like a bug in the compiler, especially because if you add the final x, x will be inferred to `never`

Comment: Actually it seems more like a missing feature, it does not work for any union type: `const f = (x: string | number) => {
    if (typeof x === "string") {
        return 1;
    } else if( typeof x === "number") {
        return 1;
    }
}` f will still return `1|undefined`. I guess typescript does not care that the missing else would never be reached according to type rules

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I think you're right. I couldn't come up with any nice workaround - you could do `... else {
    ((x: never) => {
      throw undefined;
    })(x);
  }` but this is way too ugly, I guess I'll just wait till this gets addressed, I'm sure TypeScript folks are aware of this.

Comment: I will try to find a git issue, it also happens on 2.8 so it is not fixed in the next version

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21985 ?

Comment: @jcalz That's definitely it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

Now that the `satisfies` operator is available in TS, the approach I like the best is like this:

```
if (value === "hello") {
  return "boujour";
} else {
  value satisfies "goodbye";
  return "au revoir";
}
```

or if it's a ternary,

```
value === "hello"
  ? "bonjour"
  : (value satisfies "goodbye", "au revoir")
```

If `value`'s type ends up including values other than "hello"/ "goodbye", the "satisfies" will get red-squiggled.

---

UPDATE (outdated): Actually, the best approach I think is to have a utility function

```
export const assertNever = (arg: never): never => {
  throw 'assertNever';
};
```

and use it like this:

```
if (value === ...) {
  ...
} else {
  return assertNever(value);
}
```

or (if the return type doesn't matter) like this:

```
if (value === ...) {
  ...
} else {
  assertNever(value);
}
```

or, in the case of a ternary, like this:

```
value === ...
  ? ...
  : value === ...
  ? ...
  : assertNever(value)
```

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER (outdated):

Based on discussion in the comments (thanks everyone for input), this is a missing feature ([Github issue here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21985)). The only workaround currently is to use `... else { ((x: never) => { throw undefined; })(x); }`, which is ugly but will make sure the type is inferred correctly and will produce an error if the enum is not fully exhausted.